# android - how to monitor the execution of third-party apk (inter-process communication, OS/system calls, any function calls)

Tags: android, performance-testing, sniffer

If you have an APK, but not its source code, to what degree is it possible to monitor its function calls, OS/system calls, inter-process communication?

Is it possible to wrap the target `.apk` in another `.apk` and profile its execution? (or some other method)

In Windows, there's [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/): if you launch an arbitrary `.exe` from within this utility, it will tell you all `.dll`s loaded, functions called, the works.

This is for a development environment so execution speed is not a concern.

And in case it matters, this will be Android on Intel.

Comment: If you're willing to write a custom ROM for your device, you can monitor anything.  Welcome to open source.

Comment: @GabeSechan that's not an option for my project.